# scala - calling mysql stored procedure getting error : use right near '?)' at line 1

Tags: mysql, scala, stored-procedures, jdbc

When I run this code

```
 conn = connPool.getDBConnection
  val id: String = "123456"
  val query: String = "CALL testdb.test_procedure(?)"
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
  stmt.setString(1, id)
  logger.info("DDL is : " + stmt.toString)
  val result = stmt.executeUpdate(query)
```

I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1
```

It works when I call the same procesure from a mysql client with `CALL testdb.test_procedure(?)` I have searched, it looks like I am missing something.

By the way the output is

```
136 - DDL is : sql : 'CALL testdb.test_procedure(?)', parameters : ['123456']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad, I mixed up the method signatures, coding late has some side effects.

it works just fine when this line is replaced from,

```
val result = stmt.executeUpdate(query)
```

to

```
val result = stmt.executeUpdate()
```

so the running code is

```
  conn = connPool.getDBConnection
  val id: String = "123456"
  val query: String = "CALL testdb.test_procedure(?)"
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
  stmt.setString(1, id)
  logger.info("DDL is : " + stmt.toString)
  val result = stmt.executeUpdate()
```