# java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets

Tags: mysql, scala

I am trying to run a sql query using Scala, but I receive this error: java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.
What does this mean?
This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select_All_Pokemon

BEGIN
SELECT 

PokemonName,
PokemonID

From Pokemon_Main

DELIMITER ;
```

And this is my Scala code:

```
        val statement = connection.createStatement()

        val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("sp_select_All_Pokemon")
```

Comment: this here uses parameter but it should give you a leg up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916423/scala-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-getting-error-use-right-near-at-li